# SQl 3 table comparison

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, duplicates

I am total beginner in access & sql and a new member of this great community.
now with that disclaimer aside, I need some help with the scenario below :)

I currently have 3 tables

> 1) `Performance score` (contains file numbers, names and score, one row
>   per employee)
>
> 2) `Strengths` (file number, names & strengths, many rows per employee
>   depending on number of strengths )
>
> 3) `Development Needs` (file number & Needs , many rows per employee
>   depending on Number of needs)

the problem is that when ever there are more `strengths` than `needs` or vice versa the column with less information have duplicate values to compensate for the number of the rows as per this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAf40.jpg).

is there a way to prevent the strengths & needs columns from duplicating based on the file number so that the person would have 1 strength and two needs or vice versa.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the SQL of your current query.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tedo G. said - There are no duplicates since you have two different values in the field "Need".

He gave you the SQL Server solution, the Access solution would require some VBA.
You'll need to update the SQL in the code so it returns all the Needs for a specific employee number (or whatever your primary key is).

```
Public Function JoinNeeds(EmployeeNumber As String) As Variant

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
'    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ReturnValue As String

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT Need FROM Table3 WHERE [Employee Number]='" & EmployeeNumber & "'")

    'If you get a "too few parameters" error - uncomment these lines and try again.
'    For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
'        prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
'    Next prm
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

    With rst
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
                ReturnValue = ReturnValue & .Fields("Need") & "/"
                .MoveNext
            Loop
            JoinNeeds = Mid(ReturnValue, 1, Len(ReturnValue) - 1)
        Else
            JoinNeeds = Null
        End If
    End With

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing

End Function
```

You can then use the function within your query to join the needs together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Employee Number], JoinNeeds([Employee Number]) AS Need
FROM Table3;
```

NB:  This could slow your query down a fair amount depending on the size of the table - it has to execute the code for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

There are no duplicates since you have two different values in the field "Need".

But you can concatenate the "Need" Values for each unique employee and you'll have something like this

> "Negotiation skills and Presentation Skills"

in one "Need" row.

at this point, i think you can not do this in MS Access Query, as you may have unlimited number of "Need" rows per unique employee. You need to use either VBA or SQL Server, if you have one.
SQL Server function should be like this:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @EmployeeID INT;
DECLARE @cnt AS INT = 1
DECLARE @Res AS VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @Res2 AS VARCHAR(4000) = ''

CREATE TABLE [ResultNeeds](Employeeid INT, Needs Varchar(Max))

BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [EmployeeID] FROM [Employees]

    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @EmployeeID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpNeeds') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpNeeds
        SELECT * INTO #tmpNeeds FROM [Needs] WHERE [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID
        WHILE @cnt > 0 
        BEGIN

            SELECT 
                TOP 1 @Res = [NeedName] 
            FROM 
                #tmpNeeds

            SELECT @Res2 = @Res2 + @Res + '; '

            DELETE FROM #tmpNeeds WHERE [NeedName] = @Res

            INSERT INTO [ResultNeeds] VALUES @EmployeeID, @Res2

            SELECT @cnt = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)
            FROM
                #tmpNeeds

        END


      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @EmployeeID 
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

**NOTE**: This is the sample logic, I have not tested it for real data

Comment: Thanks Tedo, much appreicated I will give it a go and let you know,